# Smarty using .html templates file

Tags: smarty

How to swich Smarty using .html templates file, not .tpl?

- templates/theme/index.tpl
- templates/theme/index.tpl

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite unclear, please add some more information.

Comment: You can also save it as templates/theme/index.html in smarty